# Django form submit using ajax Javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, django, django-forms, ajaxform

Im trying to post a form from a input datagrid table. I get a None object only, when I print the filter_list(refer the code).But when I check the data from the table by using **alert** function on success,It returns the correct selected value .I dont know much about ajax.
Please help me sort out.I attached the code for views.py,HTML below,
**In Views.py,**

```
def mytable1(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        filter_list = request.POST.get('regionwiselist')
        **print(filter_list)**
        context={'filter_list':filter_list}
        print(context)
        return render(request, 'mytable2.html', context)
    else:
        sbc = MTD.pdobjects.all()
        df = sbc.to_dataframe().reset_index(drop=True)
        df.reset_index(inplace=True)
        dict1=df.transpose().to_dict()
        dict=[]
        for k,v in dict1.items():
            dict.append(v)
        col=list(df1.columns)
        context={
                'Vertical_value':dict,
                'Vertical_header':col
        }
        return render(request, 'mytable2.html', context)
```

**In mytable2.html,**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block body %}
{% if Vertical_header  %}
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#gridContainer").dxDataGrid({
        dataSource: {{Vertical_value|safe}},
        showBorders: true,
        paging: {
            pageSize: 10
        },
        keyExpr: "RGN",
        showBorders: true,
        selection: {
            mode: "multiple"
        },
        paging: {
            pageSize: 10
        },
        filterRow: {
            visible: true
        },
        pager: {
            showPageSizeSelector: true,
            allowedPageSizes: [5, 10, 20],
            showInfo: true
        },
        columns: {{Vertical_header|safe}},
        showBorders: true
    });
  });
</script>
<div class="demo-container">
  <form id='my_form' method = "POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
      <div id="gridContainer"></div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-down"></i></button>
  </form>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).on('submit','#my_form',function data(e){
    var dataGrid = $("#gridContainer").dxDataGrid("instance");
    var selectedKeys = dataGrid.getSelectedRowKeys();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '{% url 'mytable1' %}',
        data:{
          regionwiselist:selectedKeys[0].value,
          csrfmiddlewaretoken:$("[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val()
        },
        success: function(){
            alert(selectedKeys);
          }
       });
});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function data(){
    var dataGrid = $("#gridContainer").dxDataGrid("instance");
    var selectedKeys = dataGrid.getSelectedRowKeys();
    console.log(selectedKeys[0])
  };
</script>
<button onclick="data()" type="button" name="button"></button>
{% else %}
<h2>kd:{{filter_list|safe}}</h2>

{% endif %}

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Use your debug tools to figure out what's going on: In your browser dev tools Network tab, you can see what your post request looks like (what data is submitted to your django server) and in your django code, you can set a breakpoint to view `request.POST`. That will tell you if the problem is which the way you submit the data (javascript) or the way you process it (django).

Comment: @dirkgroten As you can see my  above script I am setting a breakpoint to check my posted values(print(filter_list)). The problem is I am getting a default none value apart from the selected inputs. ({'filter_list': None} & {'filter_list': 'AP'}). The submitted data is of string datatype.

Comment: you should print `request.POST` to get a better idea of the entire request and you're not saying what your browser is sending (network tab). Show us the actual data being submitted in the HTTP POST.

Comment: @dirkgroten When i print the request.POST, it returns the <QueryDict: {}> and <QueryDict: {'regionwiselist': ['AP']}>.how can i get the  actual data being submitted in the HTTP POST

Comment: you're not preventing your form to be submitted by the browser in the default way, so you're sending 2 requests to your view. you should add `e.preventDefault()` in your `on('submit')` handler to prevent the browser from submitting the form.

Comment: @dirkgroten e.preventDefault(), it returns the submitted value but the page didn't load for the post method.

Comment: well of course not, you're sending the post request over xhr (ajax) so your javascript needs to process the response. Now it only does `alert()` but you need to write a success function that does something with the response.

Comment: Maybe [read this](https://realpython.com/django-and-ajax-form-submissions/) as an example of how this works.

Comment: I tried the below code,But it is getting looped and run endlessly                                                                                    data:{
          'regionwiselist':selectedKeys[0].toString(),
          // 'csrfmiddlewaretoken':$("input[name='csrfmiddlewaretoken']").val()
        },
        success: function(data){
            $('#my_form').submit(data);
          },

Comment: I want the post the data to views.py

Comment: You are posting the data. As you said your view sees “AP” as value for regionwiselist. So it’s working. Now you need to do something with the response.  Again, read the link I mentioned in my comment. You don’t understand the basic concept of ajax. So you need to read and understand that first.